# How to display error in frontend

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

If I have any 'require' statement in function, how can I display the error as an alert in frontend before the transaction is submitted ? For eg, ERC20 token contract, my HTML form is :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <input  type="text" id="transfer_param1" placeholder="Transfer To">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <input  type="text" id="transfer_param2" placeholder="Amount">
    </div>
    
      
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <button id="button" onclick="transfer()">Transfer</button><br>
    </div>
```

and script tag has :

```
async function transfer(){
        var p1 = document.getElementById('transfer_param1').value;
        var p2 = document.getElementById('transfer_param2').value;
        
        const result = await MyToken.methods.transfer(p1, p2).send({from:web3.eth.defaultAccount, gas:1000000})
        .then(function (result) {
         $("#viewtransfer").html('Transfer successful <br>From : ' + (result.events.Transfer.returnValues.from) + '<br> To :    ' + (result.events.Transfer.returnValues.to) + '<br> of MyToken Amount: '+ (result.events.Transfer.returnValues.value));
        console.log(result);
        });
        }
```

Basically, I don't want the transaction to be submitted and fail and waste gas.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'm doing my transactions, using ethers instead of web3js. Basically in the first `then`, ethers attempts building the transaction `tx` by also estimating the gas with RPC call. This raises a error before the proper submission if the tx would revert.

```
    async function transfer(){
        var p1 = document.getElementById('transfer_param1').value;
        var p2 = document.getElementById('transfer_param2').value;

        MyToken.transfer(p1, p2).then((tx) => {
            tx.wait().then((result) => {
                console.log("Transaction successful, result: ", result);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log("Transaction reverted, error: ", err)
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("Transaction will fail, error: ", err);
            // this works for sure if using metamask provider
            if (err.code === -32603) {
                console.log("Transaction will revert with reason: ", err.data.message);
            }
        })
    }
```